# Which permission cause Location permission being visible in Settings on Android 6

Tags: android, permissions

I have the following permissions specified in my app:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
```

My targetSDKVerion is set to 23

On my Nexus 9 running preview image with Android 6, I see in app settings `Location` permission with on/off switch but I don't really know why it's there since the only runtime permission here is `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. All other permissions belong to normal permission listed [here](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#normal)

Also on pre-M devices I can see Approximate location permission(based on network)

Can anyone explain why Location permission is presented in Android M?
[image: app Permissions settins]

Comment: What libraries are you using? See: https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html

Comment: @CommonsWare thats it. Found in merge report that one of the libraries add `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` You can write an answer so I can mark as accepted

Comment: @CommonsWare Does external libraries have the right to declare permission itself? I guess we still need to explicitly declare permission for the library itself! This is and should be the default behavior! Or may be they changed something in android M?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: "Does external libraries have the right to declare permission itself?" -- yes.

Comment: @CommonsWare any official docs?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the link. Does it mean if a library have some x permission then it is implicitly available to my app?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: Yes. See the blog post in my original comment on this question. If you have further concerns in this area, please ask a fresh Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 3):

@CommonsWare was right in his comment. I was able to find ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION in the manifest merger. Responsible library is *Google Play Services - Maps*

```
uses-permission#android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
ADDED from [com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0] .../app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-maps/7.5.0/AndroidManifest.xml:23:5-80
```

Found in that manifest that there are 4 permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

This is really unexpected since Location permission is optional for GoogleMap, at least according to their spec.

Fortunately, I have found a way to remove that permission. Manifest merger allow to remove a node like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:node="remove"/>
```

Just specify in your own `AndroidManifest.xml` which node you wish to remove on merge.